# How do I prevent my routes.rb from intercepting requests coming to /blog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rack, middleman

My `/blog` directory is just a bunch of static HTML files. That's good.

When I go to `localhost/blog` it works fine - it renders the index.html for my middleman generated blog. Great.

But when I click on any of the posts, it gives me a routing error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/blog/2015/03/11/hello_world"
```

I am pretty sure the reason this is happening is because of one of these rules in my `routes.rb`:

```
  get '/:friendly_id', to: 'posts#show'
  get '/rbt/:name', to: redirect {|path_params, _| "/#{path_params[:name].gsub(/^\d+\-/, '')}" } 
  get ':name',      to: 'posts#show'
```

I need all of these routes, but I don't want an HTML request to hit my Rack middleware unnecessarily....or worse yet, do a DB query which this error seems to suggest is happening.

How do I confine all requests to `/blog/` to just resolve to my `public/blog/` directory?

**Edit 1**

I realize the above description may not be clear. My Rails App isn't a blog, and so the `posts` you see referenced above, are not posts to the blog. They are posts of another kind, separately managed by the Rails app with a DB and all. I have since added a real `/blog` which will just be a collection of HTML articles generated by [MiddleMan](https://middlemanapp.com) that will sit in my Rails `/public/blog` folder. The idea being that the HTML files in my `/blog` directory, should not hit my Rack middleware at all.

Comment: Could you provide your post url ?

Comment: @Arv Which post URL? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: in which post you are clicking and that is giving you an error.

Comment: I am not click on any post. My site has posts, and that is separate from the blog I am trying to setup. A post is not a child of the blog. It is two different things. A post is a resource managed by Rails. My new `blog` which resides at `/blog` is a statically generated set of HTML pages compiled by Middleman (something similar to Octopress).

Comment: Can you please try with extension also like `.html`. Because it seems that you are just generating html files and putting in public folder , is n't it?

Comment: That doesn't work either. That's what I am doing, just generating HTML files and putting in public folder. The issue is that all requests like `/blog/2015...` are being intercepted by `routes.rb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force rack to serve certain folder as static and routes-ignoring by adding `config.middleware.use  Rack::Static, urls: ['/blog'], root: 'public'` to config/application.rb but imho it's better to setup a web server to intercept and serve /blog earlier than your app does.

And also in your case `/blog/2015/03/11/hello_world` seems to be a directory name, if you add `index.html` to the link it should work as you expect, without changing any configuration.

Comment: The `Rack::Static` suggestion is very interesting. It could work yes, but as you said...it is better to have the server do it, rather than Rack Middleware. Using `index.html` doesn't work, because the request never gets to my `public` folder. It simply gets redirected to my router. I know because I tried.

Answer (score 1):

When your app is run by webserver, its webroot will be the public directory. So, if you have your blog directory inside public directory this should work. `localhost/blog`

Try running with `nginx` with following config :

```
root /root/path/to/your_app/public;
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. It *should* work. But it doesn't, due to my routing rules I specified in the question above.

Comment: Okay, first of all why do you have routes defined at root level extracting params? 

I think you'll also have problem with `get '/:friendly_id', to: 'posts#show'`  and `get ':name',      to: 'posts#show'` .

Comment: I don't think you'll be able bypass rack middleware, better you scope those routes under some resource name. e.g. `get '/posts/:friendly_id', to: 'posts#show'` And this is not just because you don't have other option. But this route would be much more descriptive and represents the resource correctly. Much cleaner approach I think.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you create a `static_url` controller and configure your routes so that

```
get '/blog', to: 'static_url#show'
```

Then in your controller have

```
def show
  render file: request.fullpath
end
```

Sorry I can't test right now but I'm sure you get the idea. Also, I guess you would need to detect non-existent pages.

Comment: Yeh this could work, but then the issue here is that it would require all HTML requests to hit my Rack middleware unneccessarily. I am trying to avoid that altogether - if I can.